# swift 3 REST api - get call returns 1 byte instead of 1 (as an int), why?

Tags: rest, api, swift3, get

So I am trying to get a number from my DB. My get call returns 1 when I use postman. However when I run this code underneath, I get 1 byte.

```
func getDbVersionFromServer(callback: @escaping (_ serverDbVersion: Int16)-> ()) {
    let urlPath = "\(baseApiUrl)/users/getDBVersion"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    getTokensFromDB(){dbTokens in
    request.addValue(dbTokens["accessToken"]!, forHTTPHeaderField: "accessToken")
    request.addValue(dbTokens["refreshToken"]!, forHTTPHeaderField: "refreshToken")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200){
                        let aToken = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["accessToken"] as? String
                        updateAccessTokenOnly(newAccessToken: aToken!)

                        let dbVersion = data
                        print("here is data: \(data!) and here is dbVersion \(dbVersion!)")
                        callback(0)
                    }
                }
            })
            task.resume()
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? And how do I get my 1? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify, My get call should return the Int 1 but it returns: "here is data: 1 bytes and here is dbVersion 1 bytes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data is type of [`Data`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data) so if your response is not returning `JSON` you can use `String(data:encoding:)` to get your expected result.

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200){
            let aToken = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["accessToken"] as? String
            updateAccessTokenOnly(newAccessToken: aToken!)

            if let data = data, let stringResponse = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response \(stringResponse)")
            }
            callback(0)
        }
    }
})
task.resume()
```

Comment: that casts it to a String though right? If I want is as an Int16 can I just:
if let data = data, let stringResponse = Int16(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response \(stringResponse)")
            }

Comment: oh and It should actually be json it returns

Comment: @SteffenLefort You need to first confirm it is returning JSON or simply `1` also there is nothing like `Int16(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` but you can convert this string to Int16, Try once solution you will get your result

Comment: Yeah that worked, I just cast to Int16 afterwards. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @SteffenLefort You should use JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data to serialize your json data